# c# calc time diff between 2 countries incl DST

Tags: c#

i want to know the time difference between two countries.
There is ofcourse the static time difference, but during some periods the daylight saving time comes in between. 
As far as i know the dst period is also different for some countries, so june 1 the diff between country a and b can be 1 hour, 1 july it can be 2 hours due to DST, and 1 august it can be 1 again etc etc

Is there a framework function for it or do i have to calculate it myself?

Michel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to know:

- Both time zones (use `TimeZoneInfo` from .NET 3.5, bearing in mind that one country can have several time zones)
- An instant in time, e.g. a UTC `DateTime` or a `DateTimeOffset`.

At that point it's relatively easy: convert the UTC instant into the local time in both time zones using [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx), and subtract one from the other. Alternatively, use `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset` for both of them, and subtract one offset from the other.

Here's an example to find the current difference between London and Mountain View:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var mountainView = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById
            ("Pacific Standard Time");
        var london = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById
            ("GMT Standard Time");
        DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        TimeSpan mountainViewOffset = mountainView.GetUtcOffset(now);
        TimeSpan londonOffset = london.GetUtcOffset(now);

        Console.WriteLine(londonOffset-mountainViewOffset); // 8 hours
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out any historical difference (ie. for a date in the past when local DST policies for one or both timezones were different) you will have to store past policies for DST start/end/offset for each timezone and work them out yourself.

If you're fine with knowing the difference based on the current set of rules loaded into Windows then the built-in .NET method is straightforward and easy.

Comment: TimeZoneInfo in .NET 3.5 is meant to cope with historical changes. That's one of its benefits over TimeZone.